# Powermock integration with Guidewire

Tags: powermock, powermockito, guidewire

Anyone has successfully integrated powermock with Guidewire unit tests? I'm interrested to know what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gosu has own classloader, and PowerMock also, i think that is the main reason that dont works correctly. In my project we use Mockito, dont have static support but it works for the most common unit testing cases. Also i built a TestBase that allow make entities instances with RunLevel NONE and other utilities.

Comment: I'd be keen to see how your TestBase works? @Carlos Duque